# exec statement with/without prior compile

Tags: python, compilation, eval, exec

These weekend I've been tearing down to pieces Michele Simionato's [decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator/3.0.1), that builds signature-preserving decorators. At the heart of it all there is a dynamically generated function, which works something similar to this...

```
src = """def function(a,b,c) :\n    return _caller_(a,b,c)\n"""
evaldict = {'_caller_' : _caller_}
code = compile(src, '<string>', 'single')
exec code in evaldict
new_func = evaldict[function]
```

I have found, fooling around with this code, that the compile step can be completely avoided and go for a single:

```
exec src in evaldict
```

Now, I'm sure there is a good reason for that additional step, but I haven't been able to find what the difference between both approaches is. Performance?

And since I'm asking, could something similar, i.e. define a new function and get a handle to it, be achieved with eval? I tried, but couldn't get that to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few differences that I see. Firstly, [`compile`](http://www.python.org/doc/2.6.2/library/functions.html#compile) has slightly better semantics in the face of syntax errors than [`exec`](http://www.python.org/doc/2.6.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement). I suspect that the real reason is that the definition of `compile` is very explicit with respect to the handling of new line characters where `exec` is a little less precise.

I was curious as to why `compile` and `exec` where being used in lieu of inner functions. I didn't know that `compile`/`exec` lets you control what globals are available. Very interesting.

Comment: What about the performance? It seems that compile is faster for some reason?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  I would guess that `compile` would be faster if you are calling `exec` multiple times with the same source.  `exec` called with a string will compile the string into byte code and then execute it.  The compilation would happen on each invocation.

Answer (score 2):

compile() allows you to control the code object created and its name and source, while exec is not so flexible. it is also worth doing so that others, when reading your code, will learn they are separate steps and have this in mind later, when they need to exec the same code more than once (where compile() once, exec multiple times would be faster), and writing your code to educate the next who reads it is always a worthy influence on design choices.